# Display data in rows from one table as columns in a query result

Tags: sql, sql-server

Basic SQL question, i wish to display data in rows from one table as columns in a query result. I have two tables, table1 with a customer ID which i wish to distinctly group by, and another table2, with multiple phone numbers for each customer ID.

And to furhter complicate things, if a row in table2 has a phonenumber of 0 then another feild in that record contains an email adress, which i also wish to display
So that the output looks like this:

```
CUSTOMER ID  PHONE 1   PHONE 2  EMAIL 1   EMAIL 2 ...
232323        382389    322333  gh@gj.com  fhgh@.co.uk
345566        232356            bf@hj.com  hjgh@.co.uk
```

and so on.

Example of table1:

```
CUSTOMER ID 
  232323        
  345566
```

Example of table2:

```
Phone No    Email       CUSTOMER ID 
0           gh@gj.com     232323   
322333                    232323 
0          hjgh@.co.uk    345566  
0          fhgh@.co.uk    232323  
232356                    345566 
0          bf@hj.com      345566 
382389                    232323
```

Any help would be appriciated :)

Comment: [SQL Pivot is your answer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: If you add your query we can help you turn it into a pivot statement

Comment: Thanks for the replies. How would a pivot work here? wouldnt it a) need to be dynamic and B) i dont have a value to aaggregate and all pivot exmaples i can find are amount aggregating some value to pivot around.